# How to solve java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 24, size is 21

Tags: java, android

When I add more than 21 question to my question app and try to run it, I get the following error:

```
12-13 13:18:12.384 21277-21277/com.example.chaitanya.myquiz E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.chaitanya.myquiz, PID: 21277
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 24, size is 21
 at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
 at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
 at com.example.chaitanya.myquiz.QuestionActivity.getAnswer(QuestionActivity.java:121)
 at com.example.chaitanya.myquiz.QuestionActivity$3.onClick(QuestionActivity.java:90)
 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4759)
 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19770)
 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5237)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:912)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:707)
```

Here is the extract from the java file in which I store my questions where the error occurs:

```
//There are 30 question in the database
public List<Question> getAllQuestions() {
List<Question> quesList = new ArrayList<Question>();
// Select All Query
String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_QUEST;
dbase = this.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = dbase.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
// looping through all rows and adding to list
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        Question quest = new Question();
        quest.setID(cursor.getInt(0));
        quest.setQUESTION(cursor.getString(1));
        quest.setANSWER(cursor.getString(2));
        quest.setOPTA(cursor.getString(3));
        quest.setOPTB(cursor.getString(4));
        quest.setOPTC(cursor.getString(5));
        quesList.add(quest);
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
}
// return quest list
return quesList;
}
```

And here is the QuestionActivity class that is used in my code for the questions:

```
//QuestionActivity class
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class QuestionActivity extends Activity {
    List<Question> quesList;
    int score = 0;
    Random r = new Random();
    int qid =0;

    Question currentQ;
    TextView txtQuestion, times, scored;
    Button button1, button2, button3;
    CounterClass timer;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    QuizHelper db = new QuizHelper(this);  // my question bank class
    quesList = db.getAllQuestions();  // this will fetch all Q  
    currentQ = quesList.get(qid); // the current question

    txtQuestion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtQuestion);
    // the textview in which the question will be displayed

    // the three buttons,
    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);

    // the textview in which score will be displayed
    scored = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);

    // the timer
    times = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timers);

    // method which will set the things up for our game
    setQuestionView();
    times.setText("00:00:30");
    timer = new CounterClass(30000, 1000);
    timer.start();

    // button click listeners
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // passing the button text to other method
            // to check whether the anser is correct or not
            // same for all three buttons
            getAnswer(button1.getText().toString());
        }
    });

    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            getAnswer(button2.getText().toString());
        }
    });

    button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getAnswer(button3.getText().toString());
        }
    });
}

public void getAnswer(String AnswerString) {
    if (currentQ.getANSWER().equals(AnswerString)) {
        // if conditions matches increase the int (score) by 1
        // and set the text of the score view
        score++;
        scored.setText("Score : "+ score);
    } else {
        // if unlucky start activity and finish the game
        timer.cancel();
        Intent intent = new Intent(QuestionActivity.this,
                ResultActivity.class);

        // passing the int value
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putInt("score", score); // Your score
        intent.putExtras(b); // Put your score to your next
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
    if (qid < 31) {
        // if questions are not over then do this
        currentQ = quesList.get(qid);
        setQuestionView();
    } else {
        // if over do this
        Intent intent = new Intent(QuestionActivity.this,
                ResultActivity.class);
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putInt("score", score); // Your score
        intent.putExtras(b); // Put your score to your next
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class CounterClass extends CountDownTimer {
    public CounterClass(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        times.setText("Time is up");
        Intent intent = new Intent(QuestionActivity.this,
                ResultActivity.class);
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putInt("score", score); // Your score
        intent.putExtras(b); // Put your score to your next
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
    @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        long millis = millisUntilFinished;
        String hms = String.format(
                "%02d:%02d:%02d",
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)
                        - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
                        .toHours(millis)),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis)
                        -TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
                        .toMinutes(millis)));
        System.out.println(hms);
        times.setText(hms);
    }
}
private void setQuestionView() {
    // the method which will put all things together
    txtQuestion.setText(currentQ.getQUESTION());
    button1.setText(currentQ.getOPTA());
    button2.setText(currentQ.getOPTB());
    button3.setText(currentQ.getOPTC());
    qid= (r.nextInt(30) + 20);
}
```

Comment: id guess one of these lines `quesList.get(qid);` is failing because qid is 24 but you only have 21 questions in your list

Comment: your condition in the line above sshould be rather `if (qid < quesList.size())`

Comment: In your code `if (qid < 31) {` you are checking for `qid` less then 31 but actual size of `quesList` is 21. You can also check size of the ArrayList using `quesList.size()`. This will help in knowing what is the actual size.

Comment: if i use quesList.size()) then the resultactivity launch. that is the else condition of if(qid<quesList.size()).

Answer (score 1):

The error says every thing ,

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 24, size is 21
```

your array size is only 21 and your are trying to access 24th element of array

i guess the problem is some where at line button1 or 2 or 3, the button has text 23

also button1.getText().toString() gives string but index should be integer so do

```
int i= Integer.parseInt(button1.getText().toString());
```

and also
remove any value on button greater that 23

better check if value exists first then try to access it

```
 if(getAnswer.size()>i){

     getAnswer(i);
 }
```

similarly for other too

Answer (score 1):

xEception: `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 24, size is 21` occurs when you try to access index which does not exists.

Here in this case `quesList` size is 21 as mentioned in the exception but you are trying to access 24th index which gives the exception.

The main problem lies in this `if (qid < 31) {`. Here you are making it constant to make your program work for variable number of question returned from the database modify it as `if (qid < quesList.size()) {`.

In this it does not matter whether you have 21 or any other number of question, your program will work properly.

Comment: if i use quesList.size()) then the resultactivity launch. that is the else condition of if(qid<quesList.size()).